# Every microSD card is read only, I can't format it or write/delete data

Tags: 20.04, read-only, budgie, micro-sd

I know that there was many similar topics but I haven't find answer yet. On my Ubuntu, sd cards are everytime read only, I can't write on it or format. I can do everything on other devices (Android, Windows).
When I try to format it on gparted, I get following error:

```
error checking file system on /dev/mmcblk0p1: error when trying to detect filesystem on'/dev/mmcblk0p1': Failed to open device '/dev/mmcblk0p1' (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I tried 'sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/mmcblk0' but without succes. Any ideas?

EDIT: I can make this:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/mmcblk0p1
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk1 /media/adrian/1C14-3325/
```

Then I can write and delete on disk, but I have to repeat this everytime I unmount card and still no possibility to format or use dd command.

Comment: Had similar issue with SD card for 3d printer.  If you have a Windows OS handy, there is a SD card formater for it that seems to do a better formatting job.  This was for fat 32 type partition.

Comment: This formatter should give me possibility to write from my Linux system?

Comment: Unknown, could not write to my sd from ultimaker cura before using it and could after.  My problems were not as bad as yours either, more permissions type problems.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: Strange thing has happened. I put new sd card to the reader and I was able to write, then after removing and putting card again, the problem returned...

Comment: Please try according to all methods/tips in the list in the link from my first comment.

Comment: I tried, I can't do anything using mkusb because of the sd card is 'read only'. It looks rather permission problem than faulty of the card.

Comment: Are you making sure not to move little switch on side when putting in card?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. And for making matters even better, I can do working commands from EDIT on both positions of the switch...

Comment: Any chance of testing the cards on another machine with ubuntu on it?  Just wondering if it is the card reader being wonky with ubuntu.

Comment: It may look like either the card is faulty. But you mentioned that a new card failed and this makes me as well as crip659 suspect the card reader - it might be bad, or at least fail to cooperate with Ubuntu and/or with this computer. Such problems are rather common, because this kind of hardware is not standardized. Have you tried in another computer, maybe with Windows or maybe with another card reader?

Comment: Card worked on Windows. In Ubuntu disk manager I changed mount options of sd card to default, then once works perfect, another read only.

Comment: Mount and ownership problems can be fixed according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).